# Show dialog while load

Tags: android

I use the group to show activity in one tab.
A and B Activty are the same group.
A call B such as below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
Window w = MyGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BActivity", intent);  
View view = w.getDecorView();  
MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);
```

And BActivity is a ListActivity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.list);
RL url = new URL(urlstr);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
//extract information from is, and show in list view
}
```

I want to show dialog to show loading.
I already try AsyncTask and Thread Runnable method.
But the error `Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@2afe9488 is not valid; is your activity running?` shows.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ProgressDialog Class with the Help of Handler Class. This way you can achieve what you want to do.

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(loginAct,"Process ", "please wait....",true,true);

new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
      // your loading code goes here
     }
}).start();


     Handler progressHandler = new Handler() 
     {

         public void handleMessage(Message msg1) 
         {

             progDailog.dismiss();
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in a TabHost. So when adding your ProgressDialog don't use the Activities Context `this` to add it, instead use `getParent()` to get the Context of the TabHost: 
 `ProgressDialog pDia = new ProgressDialog(getParent());`

Comment: But I still did not get answer.

Comment: Use AsynTask to execute your download code. And in onPreExecute you have to add the ProgressDialog with my code above.